# Automatic selection of legend object in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend

I'am using the Corine Land Cover data for a projet. There is around 40 types of land use in this database. In my print composer with my scale (1:20 000) I neve have more than 10 type of land use.

I would like to show in the legend, only those 10 type of land use. Is that possible? (This option is available for the table)

I'am using QGIS master 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported. In Print Composer, it is possible to manually delete selected classes from a layer's legend entry. If the 10 land cover types don't change much from map to map, that might be an option.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. I understand this is not an actual feature. Unfortunately, land use change quite a lot around the different maps ...